# Converting pdf to LaTeX?

Tags: pdf, conversion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert PDF to (La)TeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8503/how-to-convert-pdf-to-latex)

is there a way to convert pdf to LaTeX? I don't need the conversion to be very accurate. It's fine for me as long as it is "almost there".

I found a project that looks promising
http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdf2latex/
but there are no files there.

Thank you.

Comment: The `pdf2latex` project seems to be dead or better said a still birth: No files, no docs, no nothing, not on CVS or WWW, not now, not never.

Comment: So why not trying PDF to TXT (`pdftotext` from `Xpdf` utils) then TXT to Markdown (with some manual edits or a ruby/python/perl script or whatever) and then [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/)?

Comment: Yes I second `pdftotext`, then some tool (I hacked once a Perl script together to convert `(start of line)1. Text` into `\chapter{Text}` etc.).

Comment: Sorry I didn't give enough details. It would be nice (although not essential) to be able to retain some formatting info. In particular, the pdf's that I am trying to convert has chunks of programming code scattered throughout the document and they are in monospace font. pdftotext converts the text but it doesn't preserve the typeface and I would have to write a script to try to detect the code. It would be much easier if a pdf-to-latex or pdf-to-txt tools can do this automatically. Thanks again.

Comment: I don't think you will find a suitable tool. You will need to add special environments for this kind of code anyway.

Comment: Did you try to open the pdf in OpenOffice and export it as TeX?  I don't have OpenOffice installed, and I seem to remember that the TeX code it produced was sort of messy, but you may be able to do some search and replace afterwards.

Comment: @Jan: I just tried that. OO is open it in *Draw*, i.e. as image and only allows you to export it as such. I could get the LaTeX export plugin to work with it. But I might just have done something wrong. I normally never use OO.

Comment: OO has LaTeX export? Do you mean the separate [Writer2LaTeX](http://writer2latex.sourceforge.net/)? I'm not a fan. [Abiword](http://abisource.org) has both PDF import and a TeX export options, but I wouldn't expect too much. I frankly think your best option might be Open Office's PDF import, export to RTF, and then use [rtf2latex2e](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rtf2latex2e/). I guess xpdf's pdftohtml with [pdfreflow](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfreflow/) along with [an HTML>LaTeX converter](http://www.charlietanksley.net/philtex/converting-to-latex/) might be something to look at too.

Comment: LaTeXiT (http://pierre.chachatelier.fr/programmation/latexit_en.php) can convert pdfs that he has created.