# How to convert a preprint pdf into something more readable?

Tags: pdf, conversion

I'm talking about a pdf document that was created via LaTeX (probably pdflatex) but the tex source of which is not available. I'd appreciate a solution that is less manual than trying to [convert the pdf to tex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8503/430) and then changing the style (if that even works, [the only answer there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8503/how-to-convert-pdf-to-latex/8514#8514) suggests it's far from functional).

**edit** with more readable I meaning changing the style in the original but unknown tex source such that I obtain a pdf that looks like e.g. a publication instead. This would of course in the ideal case include the pages renumbered etc. - so maybe it's impossible to achieve without texifying the pdf somehow first...

---

**edit2** For those interested in this, a [SU](http://superuser.com) question about [batch cropping pdfs](https://superuser.com/q/117762/35237)  mentions two tools that might be useful: [briss](http://sourceforge.net/projects/briss/), which crops borders (so that a two pages per page printing remains readable) and [k2pdfopt](http://www.willus.com/k2pdfopt/) which even rearranges a document's structure (untested).

Comment: @Tobias I think if there would be a better solution someone would have mentioned it... tex->pdf is pretty much a one way street and there is no going back, at least not with little effort

Comment: @MartinH: I'm afraid so...

Comment: What do you mean with "something more readable"? You want to change the style of an existing PDF? That's not easily possible if at all and would also be off-topic on this site.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: yes, changing e.g. the lineskip etc. I know this is close to off-topic, but since it is about pdfs generated by latex I thought I could give it a try

Comment: @Tobias: Changing the lineskip and the caused different page breaking is a major change for PDFs. The format isn't build for this. I don't think you will get a lot of good answers here. Asking on a different SX site might be better.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: you're right, so I tried to clarify my question that I also want page braking etc to be taken care of by latex, I just thought maybe there's an automated solution that doesn't require manual (and possibly not working) conversion into tex first. but I guess the answer will be no...

Comment: @Tobias: No, you can forget about that. Maybe Adobe Acrobat (the full thing, not the Reader) can do some of that, but I would be very surprised if it happens automatically and still looks good. PDF is simply not a format intended to be reformatted later. Adding some notes etc, yes, but not different line breaks with updated numbers... LaTeX can't help you here at all and a straight-forward high-quality PDF-to-TeX is basically not possible.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: I guess you could repost that as answer that I'd accept until proven wrong. if ever...

Comment: Regarding your edit, `pdftk` and `pdfcrop` are included in TeXLive and can do what you describe and more.  But that's not what you originally asked for.  All of that type of tool treats a page as a single entity and doesn't try to deconstruct it.

Comment: @Andrew yes, cropping is not enough for preprints. k2pdfopt actually _does_ deconstruction, but from a bitmap of each page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can forget about that. Maybe Adobe Acrobat (the full thing, not the Reader) can do some of that, but I would be very surprised if it happens automatically and still looks good. PDF is simply not a format intended to be reformatted later. Adding some notes etc, yes, but not different line breaks with updated numbers... LaTeX can't help you here at all and a straight-forward high-quality PDF-to-TeX is basically not possible.

Comment: accepted until proven wrong... knowing the document was created via latex brute-force tex creation _could_ work, but then again that's not worth the time