# Converting a PDF document to PostScript/LaTeX

Tags: pdf, conversion, postscript

I have a resume in PDF format. I have seen people linking to PostScript versions of their resume.

[I am not sure why they do that yet](https://superuser.com/q/339629/8829). How can I convert my PDF document to a LaTeX/PostScript document?

Comment: [pdf2ps](http://orion.math.iastate.edu/burkardt/g_src/pdf2ps/pdf2ps.html) or [pdtops](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/pdftops1.html)

Comment: @Marco: I would never suggest using pdf2ps, especially if the goal is to produce documents for online use... See, for example, http://stefaanlippens.net/pdf2ps_vs_pdftops for more information.

Comment: @JukkaSuomela: Very interesting. I didn't know that.

Comment: And regarding the postscript versions of resumes: they are just leftovers from 1990s; only harmful nowadays.

Comment: @JukkaSuomela: You should provide an answer ;-)

Comment: The phrase "LaTeX/Postscript" is a category error. LaTeX is (basically) a markup language; Postscript is (basically) a page description language. They are simply not comparable. Postscript can be the result of any type of initial document. (And LaTeX can in principle output different output formats, although Postscript (via DVI) and PDF are the most common.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can convert PDF to PS (PostScript) pretty easily, because they are related as both were designed by Adobe. PDF is more or less the modern re-spin of PS. However, the resulting quality might vary depending on the document and the converter. Also there should be no reason to provide PS versions of a resume nowadays. For normal users PS is outdated. It might still be useful for print back-ends in some cases.

On the other hand, it is not really possible to convert a PDF to LaTeX. There is a question about this already: [How to convert PDF to (La)TeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8503/how-to-convert-pdf-to-latex). Basically you can't recover all formatting from the PDF (or MS Word) and produce a good LaTeX code file from it.

If you already have a good looking PDF just stick with it. Alternatively you can extract the text from it (e.g. `pdftotext`) and then write a new resume with it using e.g. the [`moderncv`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/modernsv) class.