# How to convert postscript to pdf so that the result is readable on Android?

Tags: ps2pdf, android

Lots of old academic papers are distributed in `ps.gz` format. On Linux, after `gunzip`, I usually just run `ps2pdf` on the file, but the result is almost unreadable on Android phones and tablets: characters look like little dots, as if the font is not recognized. I tried several options such as `-dSubetAllFonts=True` or `-dEmbedAllFonts=True`, but nothing seems to work. Is there a way to convert those old papers in such a way that the font is acceptable for most modern systems (and Android in particular)?

Comment: can you give an example of such articles? By the way, Android is off-topic for here so SU-SE would be the place. But we might maybe (and that's a long stretch) get an answer about better handling of PS files.

Comment: Here is one example that I've been trying to convert just now: http://pllab.is.ocha.ac.jp/~asai/papers/thesis.ps.gz

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120260/making-low-quality-pdf-files-clearer/120273#120273

Comment: I saw that, but when I run `pkfix-helper asai_thesis.ps`, I get
`Reading asai_thesis.ps ... done.
Total number of Type 3 fonts encountered: 0
pkfix-helper: No Type 3 fonts were encountered in the input file` and all the fonts (except for the one Japanese subtitle, which is the only readable text) are just none in the final pdf output.

Comment: @namin If I do `ps2pdf thesis.ps` and preview the PDF file, I clearly see Type3 fonts. This is confirmed by `pdffonts thesis.pdf`. The problem for `pkfix-helper` is that these fonts are nameless

Comment: The fonts are simply stored as `f0`, `f1`, and so on.

Comment: @egreg -- what does that mean for the fix?