# latex generated pdf with multi line text puts newline after each line

Tags: itemize, paragraphs, text

I have multiline text in an `\item` of `{itemize}` or in `{section}` and creating a pdf of the document. When I copy the text from the pdf, there is a newline character at the end of each line. I am creating a document that will be read by an AI tool and splitting sentences will mess it up.

How can I configure it to not add those unnecessary newlines?

For example, if I copy the text from the pdf generated from the following code, there is a newline character between *`character in`* and *`the middle`*

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item This is some text that spans multiple lines. I need the pdf to not have a newline 
    character in the middle of the sentence in the copied text
    \item Some more text.
\end{itemize}
```

[image]

Comment: that is a feature of whatever pdf reader you are using re-constructing text to make a plain text cut and paste,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ok, but is there a way to signal the pdf reader that this is not a line ending? I am asking that because Adobe reader seems to handle MS Word generated PDFs quite well, but fails to stitch sentences for any of my latex generated PDFs. I have tested with same sentences and similar font sizes.

Comment: [Copy from PDF without line breaks at end of each line - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91567/copy-from-pdf-without-line-breaks-at-end-of-each-line) . that having said, there doesn't seem to be a known existing solution --- regardless, if someone ever made one, it could be posted there instead.

Answer (score 4):

Well this is one of the things the [Tagged PDF project](https://www.latex-project.org/publications/indexbytopic/pdf/) is about. If you compile this here in a current TeXsystem with lualatex (which handles real space chars best)

```
\DocumentMetadata{testphase=phase-III}
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item This is some text that spans multiple lines. I need the pdf to not have a newline 
    character in the middle of the sentence in the copied text
    \item Some more text.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

then copy & paste will give

```
•
This is some text that spans multiple lines. I need the pdf to not have a newline character in the middle of the sentence in the copied text
•
Some more text.
```

But generally you shouldn't put too much trust in copy&paste from a PDF. The format doesn't contain simple text and that means that every reader has to do some heuristics.

Comment: @campa I generally choose one at random from `to|too|two`

Comment: Thanks for this reference. I understand that you are working on this project and it is not yet in production stage. But, is the current implementation stable with handling simple text and bullet points?