# Symbols do not copy correctly from latex pdf to ms word

Tags: math-mode, accents, greek, msword, copy-paste

I have text containing 3 symbols in pdflatex and produce pdf. It is OK. Then i copy these symbols and paste in MS word 2013 and have another symbols or from one symbols two are produced:

> Before

```
z
{
^
```

> After

```
---
```

Here is tex text:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}   
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

before

$\digamma$   %  after copy from pdf  to MS WORD:  z

$\varkappa$  %  after copy from pdf  to MS WORD:   {

$\hat{W}$    %    after copy from pdf  to MS WORD:  two symbols

after

\end{document}
```

> Environment:

```
Windows 7
Miktex 2.9
Texworks
pdflatex
```

## Question: it is not good for users to have such pdf, how to improve situation?

Thank for your comment about post  "Copying LaTeX from a PDF" [Copying LaTeX from a PDF](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86572/copying-latex-from-a-pdf)
But it is not the same. I need the same utf8 code of these symbols in pdf (before copying) and in any rich editor (after copying), for example in ms word. It is simple: somebody will find article in pdf in internet and will take part of the text in his own information base, there it must seen exactly the same as he previousle saw in pdf version. BUT in post "Copying LaTeX from a PDF" the goal was to go back to latex code, i tried the example by Stephan Lehmke - after copying we have really latex code: $$f:\mathbb {R}\rightarrow \mathbb {R}$$ - this is not my goal.

---

That is, the currently accepted duplicate would put the LaTeX code into the clipboard if I copy the mathematics from the PDF.  This is not what I want.

When I copy the PDF output of `$f : \mathbf{N} \to \mathbf{Z_8} \cross \mathbf{Z_16}$`, I would like to paste it into another application and see something like

> *f* : **N** → **Z**<sub>8</sub> × **Z**<sub>16</sub>

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86572/15925 help?

Comment: I obtained relatively good a .docx file by choosing
`"paste as rich text format"`.

Comment: Akira Kakuto, thank you. Can you clarify: 1) do you really used pdflatex and Miktex 2.9 2) you copied from pdf to word; 3) how I can  repeat your actions,  because i can not see anywhere to choose "paste as rich text format", i have microsoft word 2013.

Comment: Thank you Andrew Swann. I have no goal to get Latex from pdf. Just we produce text  for end user with latex as pdf file. So it must be quality and for all actions of this user, because this is simple person - end user. Her is important that utf8 code of symbol in pdf and this same symbol after copieng somewhere must be the same - in this case it is not so.

Comment: OP, I've edited your question at the very end to be clear about what you're asking. Can you confirm for me that this is indeed what you want?

Comment: @vmk: Sorry I have translated from Japanese into bad English.
`Paste ---> Paste by choosing a format ---> rich text format (RTF)`
My Japanese word is 2010.

In copying from a pdf created by pdflatex, it is needed to
choose a "rectangle" to copy to clip board. If I copy as a
text, I obtain a similar result as yours.

Comment: @vmk LaTeX and Word use different fonts (postscript vs. TrueType). Therefore you will get different results as long as you don't use a font that is installed on your system in both formats.

Comment: Robert - thank you for your answer.  What font i must install in my system Windows 7 for fine copy/paste from pdf to word 2013? The all .tex text you can see above