# Image equation to TeX

Tags: graphics, equations, conversion

Is there a tool for exporting equation images to TeX? Probably something related to OCR. I have a lot of image-equations in a word document that I'd like to convert to TeX.

Note that the equations are actually images, so no word2tex-like apps would help.

Comment: It's not free and I have not used it personally but Ive seen the infty system demoed... http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WtW3bSfPaX4

Comment: Please, take a look at http://www.inftyproject.org/en/software.html#InftyReader

Comment: Crosslink: almost the same question [pdftex - How to convert PDF to (La)TeX? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8503/how-to-convert-pdf-to-latex?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 36):

## Mathpix Snip: Scanner App for Math and Science

https://www.mathpix.com/

> Mathpix Snip digitizes handwritten or printed text, and copies outputs to the clipboard that can be pasted into LaTeX editors like Overleaf, Markdown editors like Typora, Microsoft Word, and more.

Available for MacOS, Windows, Linux (Snap), iOS, and Android.

Originally starting out as a purely mobile app to scan handwritten math over time Mathpix was ported to desktop operating systems, became more powerful and acquired LaTeX scanning functionality. This was also followed by a series of price hikes and nowadays (11/2022) the free plan contains a mere 10 snips per month. Also the [privacy policy](https://mathpix.com/privacy) is pretty lousy and they collect way too much data, like scanned images, email addresses and IP addresses.

[image: Screencast]

*N.B.:* Using this to copy equations from Wikipedia is 100% pointless, because you can also just select the equation with your mouse and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>, which will put the LaTeX source of that equation in your clipboard.

Comment: It's now available in Linux as a Snap, too

Comment: I would suggest to add to the answer the fact that it is a paid app (there is a free tier that lets you convert only 50 formulas/month).

Comment: @FedericoPoloni 5USD/month... a bargain for 5000 snips...

Answer (score 10):

## pix2tex - LaTeX OCR

### *Free, Open Source*

https://github.com/lukas-blecher/LaTeX-OCR

Mathpix is freemium (can only convert a certain amount of formulas per month for free) and scribblemyscience is offline.

This is an open source alternative with a GUI. It is not the most accurate in converting the formulas and you can't convert hand written formulas but it is free and gives good results most of the time.

Comment: Abysmal documentation. Literally impossible to know how to run this.

Comment: @Cybernetic yes it isn't so good for newbies (myself included). But I managed to get it going. During the installation, you get a prompt saying something like "you should add this directory to your path". To do that you need to open the file `.bashrc` and add `export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/directory` and then restart the terminal. Then you can execute either `pix2tex` for the cli program or `latexocr` for the gui.

Comment: I'll add that for me the gui didn't work at first because I was missing some libraries. The answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/60662135 helped me resolve the issue.

Comment: The main disadvantage of this alternative is that it doesn't know how to distinguish regular text from a LaTeX equation, and will render any text as if its inside `$..$` with some font specification (e.g. `$\mathrm{text}$`). (In my testing, MathPix is capable of this distinction).

Answer (score 6):

For an open source solution, based on the algorithm introduced in {1}:

- https://github.com/harvardnlp/im2markup/ (original code, written in Lua + Python + [Torch](http://torch.ch/), MIT license)
- https://github.com/ritheshkumar95/im2latex-tensorflow (TensorFlow reimplementation, no license)
- https://github.com/yixuanzhou/image2latex (PyQt5 GUI)

---

References:

- {1} Deng, Yuntian, Anssi Kanervisto, Jeffrey Ling, and Alexander M. Rush. "Image-to-markup generation with coarse-to-fine attention." In International Conference on Machine Learning, pp. 980-989. PMLR, 2017. http://proceedings.mlr.press/v70/deng17a/deng17a.pdf

Comment: Those are amazing but they're written with python 2.7

Comment: Does this method work for handwritten formulas?

Comment: How can I run one of these on an image? I tried `image2latex` by yixuanzhou, but it uses outdated packages (Theano & Lasagne), so I can't get it to run

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Infty, there's also FFES --- the Freehand Formula Entry System. Paper on it here: http://academia.edu/156023/Handwriting_Speech_for_Computer_Entry_of_Mathematics and it's available here: http://www.cs.rit.edu/~rlaz/ffes/

Answer (score 4):

## Scribble My Science: convert images or PDF to LaTex

https://scribblemyscience.com

You can upload directly in your web browser images or PDF files. OCR technologies are used to recognize the formulas or text and to generate the LaTeX code.

Comment: sadly this page has been offline lately

Answer (score 1):

Lol, guys... Don't use the hard-path way just if you use generic formula aka you could find it on google. You just search the formula on Wikipedia then inspect the image of formula do you want and select the code it after that show the code TeX on the inspect element (and just copy & paste it) :D [image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: what if it is in pdf and not online?

Answer (score 0):

I know a lot of time has passed since the question was asked, but you can try this site: https://web.baimiaoapp.com/image-to-latex/en.

P.S. It can sometimes work poorly, but it works properly most of the time.

P.P.S. Or you can also try to use ai chat bots with photo input to convert photo with equation to tex/latex: chatgpt 4 (V) (vision) (paid), google gemini (bard) (free), microsoft copilot (bing ai) (free), llava (free), minigpt4 (free).