# Convert Image with LaTeX to LaTeX?

Tags: conversion

I have several images like the image below which have very simple LaTeX in them. I am trying to change those images into an actual LaTeX code. Is there any package which does that?

[image]

Comment: @Werner How is this a duplicate? I only have the image files and not even a pdf with the actual text.

Comment: So by image you mean a JPG or a PNG? The principle remains the same.

Comment: @Werner I'm really surprised… You can copy-and-paste from a `pdf`, and not from an image! There is some OCR involved in that latter case, and the question you link to doesn't give any clue as how to do that.

Comment: @Clément: My interpretation of the question is that "some package" should do this; alternatively put, this should be automated. Either by using something like `\includeLaTeXcode{<image>}` or via some command line `converttolatex <image>`. Perhaps a better option would be [Possible to Convert Math in Picture into LaTeX? How?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/155166/5764) or [Image equation to TeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/116863/5764)...

Comment: See if any of the answers to this question help you.  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1443/what-is-the-status-of-generating-latex-from-handwriting-i-e-ocr