# Compiling ArXiv source code of articles with images

Tags: graphics, arxiv, ebook

I have recently been trying to recompile ArXiV papers (in math and physics) based on the source code ArXiV provided (since I would like to use the geometry package to resize the articles for an ebook reader), but I've been having issues with articles with included figures and images. In most articles I've seen, such as [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0312480), the source code is unusable for my TeX editor (TeXworks), since ArXiV seems to encode the information of the images in a way that's hard to use. Is there any way to get around this and recompile these articles myself, images and all?

Comment: The file needs to be compiled with the LaTeX-`dvips`-`ps2pdf` route (`latex ver6.2`, `latex ver6.2`, `latex ver6.2`, `dvips ver6.2.dvi`, `ps2pdf ver6.2.ps`) because it embeds `.eps` files and otherwise expects DVI output (`graphicx` is loaded as `\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}`), but other than that it compiled for me and produced very sensible output. I presume you tried to compile  with pdfLaTeX? Can you tell us more about the errors you got?

Comment: The first error I get is that the text line contains an invalid character, "additivite.ps^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^"

Comment: Stupid question: Did you unpack the source code archive you downloaded? Usually when you download the source, arXiv serves you with a file that has no extension. Whenever I downloaded this file it was actually a `.tar.gz` archive that had to be unpackaged before it could be used. See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/383592/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/452215/35864

Comment: Ohhhh I see now, I assumed since there wasn’t an extension that the file had already been unzipped, but apparently not.

Comment: Yes, the extension thing is *very* confusing. The fact that the file format might be different depending on the number of files uploaded is also not helping (though most papers probably involve several files so that `.tar.gz` is almost always the right guess).

Comment: @moewe -- Your identification of `.tar.gz` as the packaging is useful.  Unless you think this should be closed as a duplicate (and even if it is), posting that as an an answer would be helpful to future seekers.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Since https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/452215/35864, which would be quite a good duplicate, is already closed as a duplicate of another, much more generic question I decided to type up something here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### tl;dr

The source files downloaded from the arXiv (via *Other formats*>*Download source*) have no file extension and are usually either a gzipped tar archive `.tar.gz` or a single gzipped file.

As a first try add `.tar.gz` to the extension-less file you downloaded and try to unpack it (using `tar` on Unixoid systems or 7zip/PeaZip or similar software on Windows).

---

The article source on the arXiv that can be accessed via *Other formats* in the sidebar

[image: Screenshot of the arXiv landing/abs page for an article. The "Other formats" link in the right sidebar is highlighted.]

and then *Download source* under the *Source* heading

[image: Screenshot of the "format selector" page of an arXiv article. Download source in the Source section near the end of the page is highlighted.]

usually leads to a file *without* any extension. In the example the downloaded file is just called `0312480`.

As the download page explains, this file may have different types depending on the submission

> Delivered as a gzipped tar (`.tar.gz`) file if there are multiple files, otherwise as a PDF file, or a gzipped TeX, DVI, PostScript or HTML (`.gz`, `.dvi.gz`, `.ps.gz` or `.html.gz`) file depending on submission format.

In any case it is extremely unlikely that the file can be opened directly. Most submissions nowadays seem to involve several files (especially when images are involved), so adding the extension `.tar.gz` (in the example we would rename `0312480` to `0312480.tar.gz`) and trying to uncompress the file (with `tar -vxzf 0312480.tar.gz` on Unixoid systems or [7zip](https://www.7-zip.org/)/[PeaZip](https://www.peazip.org/) or similar software on Windows) usually gives the right result.

Indeed, opening the renamed file `0312480.tar.gz` with PeaZip I get

[image: Screenshot of file listing of the archive in PeaZip]