# How to open the code file on arxiv

Tags: compiling, arxiv

I download the code file (tex) of articles on https://arxiv.org/. But I can not open it by texmaker. Do you know how to do this? For example,

1. Go to this [link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.03811)
2. See on the right corner
3. Choose Download: other formats
4. Choose Download source

Then how can I open the file I have downloaded?

Comment: I just tried something that worked for decades, and which worked here, too. Provided you also name the file `1502.03811`, use  `mv 1502.03811 1502.03811.tar.gz` and then `tar -xzvf 1502.03811.tar.gz`. (I am assuming you have either MacOS or Linux.) This yielded `x AnosovProper.tex
x chambers.eps
x CLI.eps
x domain.eps
x vectors2.eps`. I am, however, not sure how this question relates to TeX and friends other than the main extracted file can be compiled with LaTeX.

Comment: Often these files are actually `.tar.gz` files, but you can't always tell from the outset. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/504640/35864

Comment: If you're on mac or Linux you can use the `file` command on the command line to ask the OS what it thinks this is. It is likely to be either a tar file (might be gzipped first but not always), which is used if the source is several files. It might be a tex file if just a single source file. I agree that it would have been so much easier for everyone if they include extensions on the files. But then again not everyone knows that docx files are actually zip files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file downloaded from the link you posted has extension `.03811`. Change the extension to `.tex`, after that I'm able to open it. Note that, in order to compile without errors, you have to delete all the text before `\documentclass{...}`

Comment: Beware: one downloads   a compressed directory which contains a TeX file (>3000 lines, ansinew-encoded) and 4 .eps files.

Comment: In my computer it only downloads one file. In fact, many other source articles doesn't work for me because there are not enough files, sometimes images, sometimes bibliographies, etc.

Comment: I also download only one file, but this is a compressed  series of 5 files. I uncompressed it with 7zip.

Comment: Intersting! How different from what it does in my computer, maybe something that I don't understand with the OS? But then my answer is not good enough :(

Comment: It does not work. There is too much code that was modified and texmaker can not understand. Hence it can not read even I delete all the text before \documentclass{...} and some part after \end{document}.

Comment: Not even with the file downloaded from the link in your question?

Comment: yes, in general, for any file I download from arxiv. they always appear the sentence like this: It seems that this file can not be correctly encoded with the default encoding setting UTF-8. Then they have several choices of encoding, but I do not know what encoding I should choose. Then I choose UTF-8, it makes to much wrong codes.

Comment: I’m not sure what’s happening. The original encoding is latin1, I don’t know if texmaker can change the encoding

Comment: there is no latin1 to choose from. I hope that I can send you an image to explain what happens. You really can read the file from your computer? Could you send me the code by email: khanh.mathematic@gmail.com

Comment: Indeed my editor (TeXworks) manages to open the file if I just rename it to `1502.03811.tex`, but it then contains additional garbage before the `\documentclass` and after `\end{document}` (the latter of which is ignored), that is because the file is actually a full `.tar.gz` archive that contains not only a `.tex` file but also `.eps` image files. It is much better to rename the thing to `1502.03811.tar.gz` and extract the files before use.

Comment: thank you @moewe, it works!