# The source file on arxiv

Tags: compiling, arxiv

I want to read the source files of [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1009.0388), but I cannot compile the files.

I've read [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/528512/how-to-open-the-code-file-on-arxiv), but I could not.

I changed the extension to .tex and .tex.gz, but I cannot open it.

Also I changed the extension to .tex.gz and then tried to extract the files using the command prompt, but all I got was a bunch of unfamiliar files and no readable source files.

How can I compile this file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the extension to `.tar.gz`, not `.tex.gz`.

From there, you can extract the contents of the archive, which is a single file: `Cuboidi-2010-09-02.tex`.