# Problem with unzipping arxiv source file

Tags: arxiv

I have downloaded the source file from this arxiv article: https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.12693 which has name 2002.12693 without any extension. I added extention tar.gz and ran
"tar -xvzf 2002.12693.tar.gz" 
I get 
"tar: Error opening archive: Unrecognized archive format".

Neither unzip nor gunzip works. Any suggestion? I see this question [Compiling ArXiv source code of articles with images](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/504640/compiling-arxiv-source-code-of-articles-with-images/542189#542189) 
suggesting what I already did, but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! That's no compressed file, it's simply the `tex` file. Just add the `.tex` extension. However, this is no TeX question by itself so this question is actually off-topic here.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It is a text file. Simply add the extension `.tex` and open it with your favourite TeX editor.

Comment: The download format on the arXiv is a bit special. According to the download page they serve you with a gzipped tar archive (`.tar.gz`) if the submission consisted of more than one file and a gzipped version of the submitted file (`.tex`, `.dvi` or `.pdf`) otherwise. So you can never quite know what you get when you press download. For most papers I have ever downloaded it was a `.tar.gz`, but a few days ago I downloaded a single-file paper that was just a `.tex` (not `.tex.gz` as I expected from the explanation on the page). So if `.tar.gz` does not succeed, try just `.tex`.

Comment: To find the actual format of your file, you can use the following command: `file 2002.12693`

Answer (score 3):

The specific file that's downloaded is a simple tarball.

```bash
> file 2002.12693
2002.12693: POSIX tar archive (GNU)

> tar tvf 2002.12693
-rw-rw-r--  0 root   root    58287 Jun 15 18:49 arxiv2-casc.tex
-rw-rw-r--  0 root   root    42776 Jun 15 18:49 llncs.cls
```

Answer (score 2):

Many browsers will automatically unpack gzip files and not tell you. Try dropping the `.gz` part of the file extension, so using your example:

```
tar -xvvf 2002.12693.tar
```

will likely yield what you're looking for...unless it's a single file (in which case it's already been unpacked, and you should just rename it to `.tex`). This particular article is not a single file, so the above suggestion should work.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem on a windows computer. [Apparently tar package is added to Windows 10 version 17063.](https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/use-tar-on-windows-10)

The source file that I downloaded had the same format: *2011.xxxxx*. I added tar extension, navigated to the folder containing the tar file and run the following command:

> tar -zxvf 2011xxxxx.tar -C "D:\"

It unpacked not only the Tex file also all the auxiliary files used in submission to the folder "D:\".

Answer (score -2):

The new arXiv version has provided TeX Source option which you can download xxx.tar.gz.

---

(old answer)
You may download an xxx.xxx (without any suffix) file first, then you can rename it to xxx.xxx.zip. You will get a folder named xxx.xxx after you unzip.

Comment: No files in arXiv are .zip files.

Comment: Please see my answer carefully! You get a `xxx.xxx` (without any suffix) file, then you need to rename it to `xxx.xxx.zip`.

Comment: You misunderstand my point. arXiv does not use .zip within its infrastructure (I am an SME as an arXiv employee). arXiv's announced source is provided either as `.tar.gz` or `tex.gz` files (when the source is a singular file). There are no `.zip` files in arXiv. It is never the case that the downloaded file would be a `.zip` file from the "download source" option.

Comment: Sorry about that and thanks for your full information. I just hope to provide a solution to obtain the source file easily from arXiv.