# Having problems opening ArXiv source file in Overleaf

Tags: overleaf, arxiv

Hi have followed the instructions [in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/504640/compiling-arxiv-source-code-of-articles-with-images). Basically, I add .tar.gz to the name. Then I can compress the file into a .zip file using the inbuilt compression tool in Windows 10.

However, When I upload it to Overleaf there is nothing to show? Overleaf say that the file is empty? I have tried with a couple of papers. Any ideas?

Comment: The arXiv source is already compressed, unless Overleaf can handle gzipped tar archives, you need to **un**compress the gzipped tar to extract the files inside it, I don't believe Windows has built-in tools for this so you need something like 7zip.

Comment: what do you mean by "compress the file to zip"? a zip file containg a .tar.gz will not work. First unpack the tar archive so you have a folder of tex sources, then unzip that folder to submit

Comment: @DaiBowen windows has had tar for a few years now.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ah ok, is that just available in terminal or also accessible through Windows Explorer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert the extensionless gzipped tar file to a zip archive.

I'll assume windows. windows10 64 bit has a `tar` which can do the conversion

1. download 0312480 from arxiv.
2. Open a command window and cd to `Downloads`
3. Make a folder to hold the files

   `mkdir 0312480-files`
4. `cd 0312480-files`
5. Unpack the tar archive

   `tar -xvf ../0312480`
6. `dir` should now show all the files.
7. `cd ..`
8. Make zip archve

   `tar -a -c -f 0312480.zip 0312480-files`
9. Your `Downloads` should now have `0312480.zip` that you can upload to overleaf although that example is missing `elsart.cls`

[image]

Comment: this worked. Thank you very much