# What is the LaTeX code for this mathematical expression?

Tags: math-mode

[image]

What is the LaTeX code for this image? Please help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Image equation to TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116863/image-equation-to-tex)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) This is a simple answer, however, you should check the commands and packages specifically for the addition / multiplication / etc. on TeX.SX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{rr}
       A & B \\
    +\ 3 & 7 \\
    \hline
       9 & A
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) for using the delimeters ;)

Comment: In the original question, the $A\ B$ in the first line were right of the other two lines.  I suspect (supported by the acceptance) that was not required.  +1.

Comment: @Raaja:  presumably the delimiters you mention are the square brackets.  I haven't seen them.  What do they do?

Comment: @RossMillikan Well, here what I mean by delimeter is that using a \\ instead of a not-so-nice tab space using `&`.

Answer (score 7):

I would do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{.3ex}\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{.9}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}&$A$&$B$\\ +&$3$&$7$\\ \hline&$9$&$A$
\end{tabular}\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Another approach with `xlop`:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xlop}
\begin{document}
\oplput(1,2){A}\oplput(2,2){B}
\oplput(0,1.5){$+$}
\oplput(1,1){3}\oplput(2,1){7}
\ophline(0,0.8){4}
\oplput(1,0){9}\oplput(2,0){A}
\end{document}
```

To show also the solution you only need add some like `\vspace{1em}\opadd{59}{37}`

Comment: I think `58+37=95` is the solution of the addition, not `59+37` :)

Comment: @DũngVũ With or without taking the last carry? Because then A=5+1 and 59+37 is correct ... Ok, it was just messing, really it was only a typo... `;)`