# Alternatives to Mathpix for converting pdf to LaTeX code

Tags: pdf

I am self-learning a lot of Computer Science and Mathematics. I am using ChatGPT 4 to help me in this endeavor. Basically, if I like a set of lecture notes or if a book doesn't have solutions, I upload the relevant pages as pdf and convert them into LaTex code using Mathpix and then copy and paste the relevant sections into GPT 4 text terminal, and ask it to explain the subsection of the lecture notes in detail which it does quite well actually. The problem is that Math Pix has a limit on pdf pages and charges 0.05 us dollars for each extra page of pdf uploaded. This is a big problem, since I will be using ChatGPT 4 for literally everything, and converting hundreds of pages into LaTex code would be very expensive. Are there any alternative ways to convert PDFs that contain math equations, into LaTex code? For context, I have purchased the pro version of MathPix but still the limit is too small.

Comment: If there were a good one surely it would appear in [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/155166) [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/116863) [3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8503), no? Closing as duplicate.

Comment: Most of them convert images to LaTex, not pdf to LaTex

Comment: I would guess that the majority of available pdf in those subjects were written in latex so you could ask for the source rather than converting

Comment: That's not feasible. I am using different books, lecture notes, and other kinds of materials.