# is there a program that automatically convert old printings into TeX files?

Tags: pdf, ocr

When we download scans of old printings about math and physics, we usually see terrible typesetting like this:
[image: some formula from the 70s]

The look of it is terrible, the text is not recognized correctly (when I copy it, it says "2
:: Apj{3p =
p=l
0"), and it seems to be wasting space to store the details of the letter.

is there an auto program to make this into

```
$$\sum_{p=1}^{m}A_{pj}\beta_{p}=0$$
```

and do the same to the entire book?

Comment: Eg mathpix https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/116863/2388

Comment: This is one of the few things ChatGPT is useful for. At least, the paid version tends to do a pretty good job. You can just paste the image directly into the chat box. I don't know about doing it for the entire book, though.

Comment: speaking of which, see also [math mode - Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to/69854#69854)

Answer (score 19):

If I highlight a region of your question and paste it into

https://snip.mathpix.com

(using their free demo login, which does require you to sign up, and has some restrictions on commercial use)  I get

```
When we download scans of old printings about math and physics, we usually see terrible typesetting like this:
$$
\sum_{p=1}^m A_{p j} \beta_p=0
$$
```

as text and display:

[image]

Comment: Yup: Mathpix is _scarily_ good at this sort of stuff.  It can even recognise handwriting and double-column text, for heaven's sake.