# Generating LaTeX code from scanned LaTeX pdf

Tags: pdf

I have a paper copy of some old LaTeX notes, but I lost the source file.  If I scanned them as a .pdf, does any OCR software exist that could convert the scanned .pdf to LaTeX source (.tex)?

I also have a paper copy of some old notes created using Microsoft Word's Equation Editor.  While I am considerably less hopeful, I ask the same question -- does an OCR software exist that could convert a scanned .pdf to .tex?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: there is already an answer to this question here:
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8503/how-to-convert-pdf-to-latex

Comment: Check the linked answer, but scanned text is *much* more work (need to fix badly understood text besides redoing the formatting).