# Weird Symbols when I opened my editor today

Tags: input-encodings

Yesterday, I edited my tex document as usual, but today I opened up the file and found gibberish. Someone please tell me if I can recover the original non gibberish file. Oh, good news is that the pdf that was generated yesterday is in tact, and I saved a back up before trying to fudge with maybe fixing this crap, so if all else fails, I can retype everything from scratch...which I really would absolutely hate to do, because this file is LONG.

EDIT: No, I do not want to know how to convert PDF to Tex (because I know that is nearly impossible, and I would be better off retyping everything), all I want to know if it is possible to recover the TEX file from what it looks like below.

[image: The gibberish file]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert PDF to (La)TeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8503/how-to-convert-pdf-to-latex)

Comment: @siracusa It will never work 100% correct. I think this is only an issue of encoding.

Comment: The encoding at the bottom of the editor window is UTF-8. Is that what you saved the file in?

Comment: The thing is, we already have a lot of these questions, e.g.[here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72772/lost-latex-file-but-served-pdf-file), [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28970/recover-tex-file-back-from-compiled-pdf), [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161557/how-to-recover-lost-tex-files) or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73538/can-i-recover-my-tex-file). The one which offers the most information is the one linked to as a duplicate. I'm not sure having another question of that sort will bring any new insights.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang yes, I believe that is the usual encoding I use, but I wouldn't 100% know.

Comment: What kind of file does the operating system tell you the file is?  Can you do `file wreath_product_v3.tex` on your machine?