# Copying latex from scanned book

Tags: pdf, conversion

Suppose I have a scanned book with equations, is there a convenient way to obtain latex that reproduces them?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Did you check out the posting [How to convert PDF to (La)TeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8503/5001)?

Comment: Be aware of this: https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/issues/detail?id=270. Accepted but low priority though.