# Mathpix snip free alternative (on linux)

Tags: transformation, ocr

Are there any alternatives to mathpix? I want to be able to take a screenshot and transform any mathematics in there to Latex.
I can't use mathpix because it isn't free, and also because I am specifically using Gnome Wayland, for which the app just does not work.
Thank you for any responses.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What please is mathpix? Can you describe this better?

Comment: https://github.com/lukas-blecher/LaTeX-OCR seems promising. For others see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/145053/ or the 2nd/3rd/4th answer in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116863/image-equation-to-tex or maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266989/ocr-pdf-image-to-latex-math.

Comment: Unfortunately personally I haven't met any application similar at least in half to Mathix snip and I'm afraid there is no worthy free alternative because this program must use pre-trained model, and that to do this requires a lot of power and time, for such tasks usually rent a large computing power on Amazon servers, and since the model is trained constantly, then to rent servers must be paid constantly, therefore this program or similar a priori can not be free. But it is worth saying that you can take a ready-made model and try to do something similar, but it will take a very long time.

Comment: Hello. Mensch, mathpix basically alllows you to take a screenshot of a math formula and output the correspoding latex code. Marjin, thank you a lot, the first link especially seems very promising, and I will install it and keep you updated. Antn Mn, I understand the difficulty of such a task, and paying would not bother me per se, but the fact the app does not work on my specific environment is too bad, After I try the project that Marjin first linked, I will write a follow-up, whether the program worked or not. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 7):

I'm develeping Pix2Text (P2T), which combines Latex-OCR and CnOCR, and can recognize text or mathematical formulas. More Intro here: https://github.com/breezedeus/Pix2Text/blob/main/README.md

Pix2Text is expected to be an open source Python alternative for Mathpix, accomplishing similar functionality to Mathpix. Currently Pix2Text can recognize Math Formulas, English, or Chinese Texts in screenshot images. The following is the procedure.

[image: Flow]

Pix2Text first trains an image classification model to determine the image type, then based on different image types, the image is sent to different recognition systems for text recognition:

- If the image type is `formula`, which means the image is a mathematical formula, then LaTeX-OCR is invoked to recognize the mathematical formula in the image and return its Latex representation.
- If the image type is `english`, which means that the image contains English text, at this time the English model in CnOCR is used to recognize the English text in it; the English model is better than the general model for screenshots of text in pure English contexts.
- If the image type is `general`, which means that the image contains general text, at this time `general` model in CnOCR is used to recognize the Chinese or English text in it. In the future the image types will be further subdivided according to the application needs.

---

In the near future, I will release a new version of P2T that supports more general scenarios (recognize a picture with both text and mathematical formulas)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try https://math-editor.online. It can undertake free and unlimited math ocr task, as well as math visual and raw editing.