# How is a mathematical formula represented in PDF?

Tags: pdf, input-encodings, font-encodings, bitmap, extract

If I compile a .tex file to a PDF, how will the PDF encode a mathematical formula like f.ex. the integral below? Is it a bitmap? Or how else is it encoded? And how can I extract the formula from a PDF file?
[image]

Some more context: My goal is to train a neural net to output the latex code when I give it a mathematical symbol like the integral above as an input. The first step for this would be to find out how the symbol is represented in the PDF file so I can extract this part and use it as a label for the training data.

Thanks

Comment: Sees like a duplicate (or related to) [How to convert PDF to Latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8503/how-to-convert-pdf-to-latex)

Comment: Just FYI, there is a commercial program (not free) called "PDFtoMusic" which does this kind of thing, for musical notation. It can actually play the music (and sing with synth voice, too). But the PDF must be generated by a music notation program, so that PDFtoMusic knows how to decode it. Scanned sheet music does not work (that is, no bitmaps). I mention this, merely to show that your goal is not futile.

Comment: Something that already does this: https://mathpix.com/

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Essentially in pdf every letter (or run of letters) is positioned by coordinates so even a normal word might be encoded as individual letters positioned to "look" like text, so as to take account of inter-letter kerns etc.

Math is no different: the characters are just normal font characters positioned on the page at locations that TeX has determined.

PostScript uses the same rendering model as PDF but is a bit easier to read by eye, Taking Henri's example and using latex and dvips

```
\documentclass{article}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
$\int_0^2 x^2 dx$
\end{document}
```

Produces the following PostScript

```
%%Page: 1 1
TeXDict begin 1 0 bop 639 457 a Fc(R)695 477 y Fb(2)678
553 y(0)746 524 y Fa(x)793 494 y Fb(2)830 524 y Fa(dx)p
eop end
%%Trailer
```

where you can see the structure: strings are encoded as for example `(dx)` for dx and but apart from that 2 letter example all other character runs are single characters with the font and coordinates specified separately for each letter.

Comment: Add a colon after *Math is no different*.

Comment: @TRiG done :-).

Answer (score 10):

For my opinion (I hope to have understand well) you could use a special tool called `MaxTract`. It can be found at the link http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/research/groupings/reasoning/sdag/maxtract.php.

Maxtract is a tool for converting PDF into formats such as LaTeX, MathML and text.
[image]

**ADDENDUM**: Could this program [PDF to LaTeX converter](https://www.pdfconverters.net/how-to/how-to-convert-pdf-to-latex-without-efforts-and-for-free/) also be useful?

[image]

Comment: You already know this, but for the benefit of others who find this thread: One of the principles of Unicode is that each character has a semantic meaning. This, the summation symbol us U+2201, but the Greek capital Sigma is U+03A3, even though they may look the same. This semantic difference is one way that automation can discern the meaning.

Comment: PDFtoTxt is Windows only.

Comment: Maxtract never returned anything for a 86MB textbook.

Answer (score 9):

If you use a Unicode math font, then all of the glyphs are just Unicode symbols in the resulting PDF.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
$\int_0^2 x^2 dx$
\end{document}
```

```
$ pdftotext test.pdf -
2

∫ 2 
0
```

Comment: I did not understand the question, did you? :-( I'm upvoting your answer. But why I have not understood the questions?

Comment: @Sebastiano »find out how the symbol is represented in the PDF file« is the key point here (I presume).

Comment: Boh! I have seen the tag `bitmap` :-(

Comment: So there is no additional information regarding position or font for example in the resulting PDF file? (+1 of course)

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner PDF was originally intended as "digital paper" in which the characters had no semantic meaning. Over the years, many features have been added, with the emphasis on electronic files rather than pre-print. As far as I know (which is very little), it is possible to add semantic meaning using accessibility tags. However, the TeX capability (`accsup` package) is very limited, and the job is very labor-intensive with professional software (Adobe Acrobat Pro).

Comment: @RobtAll Thanks for the explanation. I was wondering how the PDF reader chooses the font in the example above.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner For the above example, I doubt if the PDF reader chooses font based on semantic meaning, because I doubt that the original PDF had such meaning encoded. But as long as Unicode is used, there is a specific character for (say) the integral sign. There are also specific characters for superscripts and subscripts, which are different from the same characters merely moved up or down. An equation using Unicode-specific characters has some built-in semantic meaning, for simple equations. But that does not work for matrices, or other situations specifically using position.