# How to make Pandoc convert latex to Word format keeping citation, caption in figures and code cells?

Tags: bibliographies, pandoc, latex-to-word

Using `pandoc -o file.docx file.tex` it returns a Word document without code, citation, and also the caption of the figures.

P.S. Regarding the citation my bibliography is included in the latex document as

```
\begin{thebibliography}
\bibitem{}{}
\end{thebibliography}
```

Is there a way to convert the to Word format keeping the code cells, citations and caption?

Comment: Try converting the PDF?

Comment: To get your in word, you have to use `pandoc-citeproc`, which needs the bibliography as a special file, e.g. `.bib`

Comment: @OlegLobachev is it possible to convert from pdf to Word using Pando?

Comment: @DG' do I need to copy past `\begin{thebibliography}
\bibitem{}{}
\end{thebibliography}` inside another file?

Comment: I fear that won't be enough. You have to create a proper `.bib`-file.  Maybe you can use [bbl2bib.pl](https://ctan.org/pkg/crossrefware). You should look into [tex4ht](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/486194/29873) as an alternative.

Comment: Since manual `thebibliography` is not `biblatex` (and not compatible with `biblatex` either) I have removed the `biblatex` tag and replaced it with the more generic 'bibliographies'.

Comment: @walid: No, but see, e.g., https://www.docx2latex.com/ or https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8514.

Comment: @DG' I did specify a `.bib` file, how can I use `pandoc-citeproc` to show up citation?

Comment: @walid - `pandoc --bibliography file.bib --filter pandoc-citeproc -o file.docx file.tex`

Comment: @DG' Thanks a lot! It is normal to have the name of authors (names) instead of enumeration e.g. [1]?

Comment: Yes, that's the default style. You can choose an download others from https://www.zotero.org/styles (and specify `--csl file.csl`. This is all very well documented in pandoc's manual: https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#citations

Comment: @DG' Thanks a lot! that was helpful regarding the citation problem :)