# What are my options if tex files are unavailable?

Tags: pdf, tex-core

This is a rather morbid question; sorry for that.

A friend recently passed away. Prior to passing, he had submitted some of his work to a journal. Journal editor has reached out to see if I could help with some non-controversial copy editing and providing a source file (only PDF had been submitted). We're going to confirm with the family that they're OK with this. If we proceed, is there anything I can do short of entirely recreating the tex file by hand?

Comment: My condolences for your friend. Does this answer your question? [How to convert PDF to (La)TeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8503/how-to-convert-pdf-to-latex)

Comment: I would like to offer my condolences as well. Forgive me if you have already considered this, but would it be in any way possible to access your friend's computer and search for the tex file? Or move the hard drive to another computer in order to read the contents in case the password for the operating system is lost?

Comment: @Marjin Yeah, I'll have to ask his family about it. I'd want to give them some time first.